# Any valid reason to force old maven plugin versions?

Tags: java, maven, project, pom.xml

I work on a big legacy project and I've noticed that in the project root pom we explicitly forced certain maven plugin versions.

I've read about the 'maven way' and it seems to me that this is a violation of this way - forcing versions instead of inheriting them from the superpom. Here's an example of what we have in the project pom:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>...</configuration>
            </plugin>
```

My question is - what are the valid reasons (if any) to force plugin versions like that. I wonder because often times I find code that was written without any clear purpose and I do wonder if this is such a case, and if I should just drop the version from the project root pom.

Afterthought: On this [site](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-version-ranges) they say:

> When declaring a "normal" version such as 3.8.2 for Junit, internally
>   this is represented as "allow anything, but prefer 3.8.2." This means
>   that when a conflict is detected, Maven is allowed to use the conflict
>   algorithms to choose the best version. If you specify [3.8.2], it
>   means that only 3.8.2 will be used and nothing else.

So this means, if you force the version to ensure stability, then you should also use [] otherwise maven is free to ignore your forced version.

Answer (score 3):

The best is to define plugins versions only in a corporate pom and of course mainain this corporate pom over the time which means update the plugins versions from time to time.

This means in consequence that in no other project it is needed or better should be prevented to use a different versions of plugins (except there are very good reasons for this bugs in plugins).

Furthermore the excerpt you have given is an example of bad practice cause plugins and/or their configuration should be defined by using **pluginManagement** instead.

So if a project needs an older version of a maven plugin there should be at least a comment in the pom which describes why it's using not the inherited version. May be with a link to an appropriate JIRA issue...

Comment: Thanks for mentioning pluginManagement. I have to read up on that.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been stated, this can be because of corporate reasons - using new versions of plugins can break tests, functionality or even a whole product itself; new versions have to be tested thoroughly, advanced teams even need to discuss them because it can **change** the product in many ways.

Not forcing versions will create some kind of unstable situation during the next big build - which is always unwanted, developers dont like randomness :). 
If your POM only describes a small, private project or maybe even a small community project you may very well let maven do all the version-management but thats pretty much a no-go for professional products which are worth .... say hundreds of thousands or even millions of currency units.

Answer (score 1):

> what are the valid reasons (if any) to force plugin versions like that.

A valid reason is to keep a build repeatable, especially if there are known problems with a later version of the plugin. This ensures that the specific version is used, rather than a later version from an organisational parent pom (or, worse, from the default with no version specified anywhere).

> I wonder because often times I find code that was written without any clear purpose and I do wonder if this is such a case

It's very possible, in a large code base, that this is exactly the case. The plugin configuration could have been copied from somewhere else and the version included without a good reason.

> and if I should just drop the version from the project root pom.

If there is no reason given, either in a comment or a commit message, and if the same plugin has a version specified in the parent pom *and* if the build still works perfectly without it, then you should drop that version.

If it *doesn't* work, you should either fix the build or add a comment explaining exactly why this version is necessary.

Comment: the expression "works perfectly" is a very brave one - without full testing (manual _and_ automatic) such a statement can be discarded, in most cases it will be untrue.